# Getting QPushButton's coordinates

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am using pyqt to do this so how can I get the coordinates of a specific button. 
For example:

```
button = self.ui.buttonGroup.button(buttonId)
```

I want to change this button's coordinate according to its current coordinate. How can I do that?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve by attempting to do this?

Comment: I believe I answered your question, but I think too that ekhumoro is right. Perhaps there is an easier way to achieve what you want. Manually placing widgets is almost always a wrong choice.

Comment: I am kind of new to pyqt. To warmup i am writing a puzzle game(8-puzzle, sliding puzzle). User can insert the dimensions. When user click to buttons i will move them to do that i needed the coordinates.

Comment: @SegmentationFault. If you'd mentioned the puzzle, it would have made your question much more interesting, and possibly got more answers. What you need is a grid of _nine_ buttons, one of which is hidden. When a button is clicked, change the text of the hidden button to the text of the clicked button. Then show the hidden button, and hide the clicked button. There's no need to actually move the buttons at all...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All PyQt Widgets inherit the methods of their base class [QWidget](https://pyqt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/qtwidgets/qwidget.html). If you check the documentation you will see that there is a great variety of methods and attributes related to the geometry of each widget. Copying from the previous link, these are the following ones:

> pos, x(), y(), rect, size, width(), height(), move(), resize(), sizePolicy, sizeHint(), minimumSizeHint(), updateGeometry(), layout(), frameGeometry, geometry, childrenRect, childrenRegion, adjustSize(), mapFromGlobal(), mapToGlobal(), mapFromParent(), mapToParent(), maximumSize, minimumSize, sizeIncrement, baseSize, setFixedSize()

In order to get a better understanding of what they do check them out interactively. I believe that geometry is the one you need.